# An error occurred while deserializing the field of class, Specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I try to deserializing a complicated object look like the example below, and getting this runtime error:

```
An error occurred while deserializing the LastJobs field of class sqCore.sqTask: 
An error occurred while deserializing the QueryResult field of class sqCore.sqQueryJob: 
An error occurred while deserializing the Titles field of class sqCore.sqQueryResult: Specified method is not supported.
```

This is the object (I tried to take only importent parts of it.. Hope that works)

I guess the problem is in the "RuntimeType" or in the "Null"
But I don't know how to fix it.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("528fc2412feaa3230854e000"),
  (...)
  "CurrentJobs" : 
      [{
         "_t" : "sqQueryJob",
         "Result" : { },
         "DB" : {(...)},
         "QueryResult" : null,
         (...)
      }],
  "LastJobs" : 
      [{
         "_t" : "sqQueryJob",
         "Result" : { },
         "DB" : {(...)},
         "QueryResult" : 
           {
           "Titles" : [["LogTime", {"_t" : "RuntimeType"}], ["TaskName", {"_t" : "RuntimeType"}], ["LogMessage", {"_t" : "RuntimeType"}]],
           "Params" : [[ISODate("2013-11-22T20:44:42.433Z"), "MainApp", "MSSQL DB connection has been made."]]
           },
      }],
  (...)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the C# classes you're trying to serialize into? Have you tried just a simple `BsonDocument`? Does that work?

Comment: hi @WiredPrairie, here is the source code of 2 of the class (where the error happend)

The Task class: http://pastebin.com/wWxsHC52

the Result Class http://pastebin.com/JN20ywZy

Comment: Does it work to create a new instance, populated, and save one of those? My head spins trying to understand how MongoDB would (de)serialize those structures. :) If you really need that complexity in your data model, you might look into the custom serializer support in the C# MongoDB driver. *Arrays of arrays are poorly supported if you need to do much with them.*

Comment: Well.. I have a lot of instances of the sqTask and I Have to dump them to the Hardisk and reload them..
so the answer is "No Mongo"? @WiredPrairie

Comment: If it won't save, it won't load. So, I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: (I'll blaim my poor english in this..) || nevermind, I found that the problem realy was in the "RuntimeType". When I remove it the code run fine and looks good. Thanks for your help! @WiredPrairie